# Typing onClick function in onKeyDown handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, onclick, handler, onkeydown

There's keyDown handler to the onClick function, that has been passed to the component as a prop.
The keydown is for accessibility matters, so the onClick could be fired also with Enter and Space keys. 
As onClick is mouseEvent, but keyDown is keyboardEvent, I'm not sure what the type for the function onClick in handleKeyDown should be. 
And if it stays as any, wouldn't it brake anything in some edge cases?

```
interface ComponentProps {
    onClick?: (**event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>**) => void;
}

function handleKeyDown(**e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>**) {
            if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.key === ' ') {
                e.preventDefault();

                onClick!(**e as any**);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could type it as a union type of both MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent, and inside your handler use a type guard to refine the type. This way, TypeScript will know what type it's passing to onClick.

But, another thing to consider, specially for accessibility, is why you have a div that is clickable? Could you use a button instead? Buttons are accessible by default and work both with mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Oh that's worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! The case with using the div is that this button contains other components as well, so the div is made accessible in this case. But good point, that for accessibility matters it's always better to use proper HTML elements :)

Comment: Can you show a code example please?